# Is there any legal principle supporting the refund of plane tickets sold to non-existent person?

Tags: online, air-travel

The names below have been changed to protect the guilty.

Suppose **John Smith** goes online to buy plane tickets for himself and his wife, **Jane Maiden Smith**.

Due to human error and browser autocomplete, Jane's name is accidentally entered as **Josh Jane Maiden Maiden**.

**Josh Maiden** happens to be Jane's father, but it is likely no person actually exists on earth with the name **Josh Jane Maiden Maiden**.

The 24-hour cancellation grace period passes and the error is not noticed.

Days later, Adamant Airlines is contacted and refuses to fix the name, but agrees to cancel ticket for *credit to be used later by the same person*.

Given that the person named on the credit does not actually exist, is there any legal principle which could be cited in an attorney letter to encourage the airline to issue a refund?

Comment: A competent attorney who you might engage to write such a letter would be able to tell you better than some random folks here.  Most attorneys will provide a free initial consultation but don't be surprised if the cost of pursuing this with an attorney exceeds your damages.

Comment: @jwh20 the cost of me taking an hour of my day to talk to an attorney exceeds my damages. I still would like to know the applicable legal principles. This site is for EDUCATIONAL PURPOSES after all, so please educate me.